# Why this function is not called properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script where i take an integer from player prefs.
Below in code i am comparing value taken from player prefs and value taken from script name,casted to integer.In debug I see that values are changing f.e
first is 1 and second is 1,then after i button click,one value is increased by 1,and now
first is 1 and second is 2.But my code executes same as first time,but it should behave diferrently bcs if values are same it should do this,and if values are diferent it should do that.
Below is my code
Problem is when i use value from PlayerPrefs.

```
 nazivKategorije = PlayerPrefs.GetString("kategorija");
        if (nazivKategorije == "male")
        {
brojOA = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BrojOdgAsocijacije");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("BROJOA", brojOA);
        }else if (nazivKategorije == "srednje")
        {
            brojOA = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BrojOdgAsocijacijeS");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("BROJOA", brojOA);
        }
        else if (nazivKategorije == "velike")
        {
            brojOA = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BrojOdgAsocijacijeV");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("BROJOA", brojOA);
        }
        Debug.Log("NAZIV KATEGORIJE" + nazivKategorije);

   
//If I declare int above,and use its values there is not problem with this part of code.
```

In other script i increase this PlayerPrefs values.So to repeat:
when i had one value declared above,on top all worked fine.Now when I added this values from PlayerPrefs code wont run,actualy dont compare if:
brojBroja == broj or NOT.
First time it compare,and then it doesnt,It just throw first part of code no matter are values equal or not.

```
 private void OnEnable()
        {
   
            int brojBroja= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BROJOA");
    
    
            if (brojBroja == broj)
            {
               GameEvents.OnBoardCompleted += ShowKonacnoRjesenje;
            }
    
            if (brojBroja != broj)
            {
                GameEvents.OnBoardCompleted += nePrikazujOpet;
            }
                 
        
        }
    
    
        private void OnDisable()
        {
           
    
    
                GameEvents.OnBoardCompleted -= ShowKonacnoRjesenje;
    
                GameEvents.OnBoardCompleted -= nePrikazujOpet;
      
    
        }
```

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve].

Comment: i think you are confusing `+=` with calling the function. With `+=` you are subscribing to an event. In other part of the code if you do `GameEvents.OnBoardCompleted?.invoke();` the subscribed method will be called, `ShowKonacnoRjesenje` in your case if previously subscribed

Comment: I am subscribing Event,but I want subscribe different events depending on this int values.If they are equal i want do 1,and if they are not i want do 2.

Comment: In general you should rather use `switch - case` instead of all these `if` checks